# jQuery AJAX Cross Domain with BASIC Authentication

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I'm attempting to make use of the Beanstalk (beanstalkapp.com) API by pulling data into a webpage so people can view it without accessing my SVN.

What I'm doing to try and access it is by using an AJAX request through jQuery. The code is below, but I get an error each time, and can't return the data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tok = 'username' + ':' + 'password123';
        hash = btoa(tok);
        authInfo = "Basic " + hash;
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://username.beanstalkapp.com/api/changesets.json",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", authInfo); },
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success:  function(html){
            console.log(html);
        },
        error: function(html){
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

If I access the URL straight through my browser (http://username.beanstalkapp.com/api/changesets.json) it works just fine and returns the json. However, I cannot get the AJAX to return it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure that the server/page (or whatever) allows request via Ajax.

Comment: how did u provide username and password when u call through an ajax

Comment: Bishnu- Would there be another way to get the data remotely?

Comment: muthu- It's in the script above. It's the var 'tok'.

Comment: I ended up just writing a cURL script to do this. The server must not like being pinged by AJAX. If anyone would like to see it, let me know and I will edit the question.

Comment: Why dint you accepted answer that suggesteed you to use curl than?

Comment: **I wrote an answer for this question here:
[Loading cross domain html page with jQuery AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-jquery-ajax/17299796#17299796)** – _the last one, supports https_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to make proxy for cross-domain ajax requests.

Usual scenario looks like this:

1. Client send ajax request to server
2. Your server forwards request to external/remote server
3. Waiting on response from remote server
4. Parse and process response from remote server
5. Send response back to client

If you are using php you can send requests with curl, and it is pretty easy to implement. I have wrote article on this topic recently http://www.svlada.com/proxy-ajax-requests-curl-and-symfony-2/.

Answer (score 1):

you cant get a json from other domain than yours. this is a security issue called [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) to get over it use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RvWb4/). The username and password is incorrect. Give the correct username and password and check it once again.

Comment: Even with the right password it was giving me the same auth error.

Comment: I got error like this GET http://aaronh.beanstalkapp.com/api/changesets.json?callback=jQuery180029055113159120083_1344931716444&_=1344931716450 401 (Unauthorized)