# ajax to login to a website clients side

Tags: ajax, cors

What are some sources for using ajax to login into sites that allow cross origin resource sharing?

If a person has a website how can the send a password and username to another site to login and also get information from another website?

Any good resources? 
Not using a server, client side only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery then it already contains settings for basic authentication (username/password).  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

[Cross-domain ajax request basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689496/cross-domain-ajax-request-basic-authentication)

[jQuery AJAX Cross Domain with BASIC Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946307/jquery-ajax-cross-domain-with-basic-authentication)

http://techblog.constantcontact.com/software-development/using-cors-for-cross-domain-ajax-requests/

Comment: Is it possible that none of this is working because of same-origin policy?